# "textTransform" issue with [Material UI + Typescript] makeStyles / createStyles with props

Tags: typescript

For some reason typescript is giving me an error with the `textTransform: 'none'` property.

```
const useButtonStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => createStyles({
  // @ts-ignore
  root: (props) => ({
    boxShadow: 'none',
    textTransform: 'none',
    borderRadius: 3,
    border: '1px solid',
    backgroundColor: theme.palette[props.color].main,
    borderColor: theme.palette[props.color].main,
    color: theme.palette.getContrastText(theme.palette[props.color].light),
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette[props.color].light,
      borderColor: theme.palette[props.color].light
    },
    '&:active': {
      boxShadow: 'none',
      backgroundColor: theme.palette[props.color].light,
      borderColor: theme.palette[props.color].main
    },
    '&:focus': {
      boxShadow: `${fade(theme.palette[props.color].light, 0.25)} 0 0 0 0.15rem`
    }
  }),
}));
```

Comment: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16307

Answer (score 1):

Adding `any` to props seems to fix it.

```
const useButtonStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => createStyles({
  root: (props: any) => ({
    boxShadow: 'none',
    textTransform: 'none',
    borderRadius: 3,
    border: '1px solid',
    backgroundColor: theme.palette[props.color].main,
    borderColor: theme.palette[props.color].main,
    color: theme.palette.getContrastText(theme.palette[props.color].light),
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette[props.color].light,
      borderColor: theme.palette[props.color].light
    },
    '&:active': {
      boxShadow: 'none',
      backgroundColor: theme.palette[props.color].light,
      borderColor: theme.palette[props.color].main
    },
    '&:focus': {
      boxShadow: `${fade(theme.palette[props.color].light, 0.25)} 0 0 0 0.15rem`
    }
  }),
}));
```